# What are good techniques for getting gluten free bread to rise?

Tags: bread, baking, gluten-free

I make gluten free bread in a [bread maker](http://www.breville.com.au/products_detail.asp?prod=480), however I can never get it to rise as much as 'regular' bread and is usually a little heavy. What techniques/recipes/substitutions can I try to get my gluten free bread to rise more?

I currently use a recipe that is similar to this one [here](http://www.cookingbread.com/recipes/gluten_free_bread/gluten_free_farmhouse_bread_recipe.html), but with a bit of tapioca starch instead of buckwheat flour.

Comment: FYI buckwheat flour is gluten free so you dont need to replace its use. Buck wheat confusingly is not actually a wheat.

Comment: @Toby Thanks for the tip, however I add tapioca starch for flavor. The gluten free flours appear to taste as though they have less starch than wheat based varieties.

Answer (score 3):

Baking soda comes to mind. Irish soda bread can be gluten-free, and uses baking soda for its rising action. The crumb is fairly loose though, did you want something that would hold together better?

Comment: @roux Thanks for the tip - I have never tried Irish soda bread before and will give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

You need something to make the batter a little more sticky so that bubbles from yeast or baking soda stay trapped as the bread bakes.

I generally use a little bit of xantham gum and a couple of tablespoons of arrowroot flour.

To make sure they're fully hydrated (for optimal sliminess) let the wet batter sit for a couple of minutes before adding baking soda.  A little lemon juice or vinegar in the wet ingredients will help too.

Comment: +1, I use apple cider vinegar in my baked goods and it really does help, especially with muffins and cupcakes.

Answer (score 1):

I have had problems using bread makers myself, and therefor don't use them anymore. I have added my best tip for gluten free yeast baking in the thread [Gluten free cooking](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4628/gluten-free-cooking). At least this works fine for me, and my girlfriend actually envy me for my nice bread, which tastes and looks better then the ones she buy in the store.